# Interpret $\prod_{n=3}^\infty 1- \frac{1}{n\choose 2}$ as a probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, infinite-product, combinatorial-proofs

Find the infinite product

$$\prod_{n=3}^\infty 1- \dfrac{1}{n\choose 2}$$

It is quite simple to expand and cancel alternating terms to obtain $\frac13$ as the answer.
However, notice how the expression looks the product of "not" probabilities of some event iterated over different sample spaces. All I want is a simple probabilistic proof of this evaluation.

One can do this by finding a bijection between this expression and that event. For example, I thought of the situation as having bags having $2,3,4,\dots$ balls respectively. Now we select $2$ balls from each bag one by one, and write the probability of not coming up with a specific pair of balls from each bag. This is exactly equal to the given expression.

**Update**: Check @Ian's answer for such a bijection. Now the problem remains to connect it to 1/3.

Answer (score 3):

A simple interpretation: you have a bag containing two red balls and a blue ball. You draw two balls, at least one is blue. You replace the balls you drew and throw in another blue ball. You draw two balls, at least one is blue. Your quantity is the probability of this chain continuing forever, instead of being terminated by drawing both of the red balls at some point.

Comment: Yeah good... but let's search for a way to write this probability as some other workable expression.  i.e., LHS = Situation = RHS, where LHS is the question and RHS is a rewritten workable "answer".

Comment: @user567629 I don't understand your meaning at all.

Comment: @Ian I think they are trying to say that they want a probability space and event $E$ where the equalities $P(E)=\prod (1-\binom{n}2^{-1})$ and $P(E)=1/3$ are both obvious. In your situation, only the first is obvious. That is, they want a clever, probabilisitic proof that $\prod (1-\binom{n}2^{-1})=1/3$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I'm not sure how easy that's going to be to do...consider that the analogous situation where there is just one red ball has a completely different outcome (in that case the limiting probability is zero, a consequence of the divergence of the harmonic series).